# Canvas pure draw vs png image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

which is faster (complex drawings). fillRect or reprint a png image drawImage. when reprint 10000 objects.

```
ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";//RED COLOR
ctx.fillRect(0,0,50,50);
```

**VS**

```
ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawImage` is actually faster.

I've updated the test case with a 50x50 PNG: http://jsperf.com/canvas-draw-methods

In Firefox it's only slightly faster, but in Chrome the difference is huge, with `drawImage`  being faster by an order of magnitude.

(Note the previous version of the test was wildly skewed since the PNG I was using was not the right size. Image size makes a big difference.)

Comment: That is a terrible terrible test case. You're comparing drawing a 50*50 square with a 432*505 image. Of course the smaller one will be faster. Here is an update: http://jsperf.com/canvas-draw-methods/2 (The result is the same, but the difference is lower, more like 40%)

Comment: then maybe miss the fillRect advantage if you have to draw something complex.

Comment: You're right, that test case was horrible. I updated it with a properly sized image and the `drawImage` method does seem to be a lot faster now. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I make a new test with a loop of 10,000 complex drawings with fillrect and drawImage. FillRect takes  596.000ms and drawImage takes 29.000ms. is a real difference.